# Is it haram to use pills to avoid or offset menstruation?

Tags: practical-islam, women, menses

I live very far from my wife and family for job. I usually go my home for 7 to 8 days maximum. The problem is whenever I visited my wife, she usually had been with her monthly days. She took *regestrone 5mg* to avoid her timings. Is it halal or haram?

Also I cannot take my wife with me due to her studies for at least next 6 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK. There is nothing wrong with taking medication to regulate human functions. However, two rules must be adhered to are:

1. Taking such pills must not result in putting her life and health at risk.
2. It is better, before taking such medication, to seek the advice of a reliable physician.

[Fatwa Source](http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-the-scholar/acts-of-worship/fasting/conditions-of-a-valid-fast/175037-women-taking-pills-to-stop-menses-during-ramadan.html)

Comment: Thanks  for the answer and link. Also my wife is a medical final year student and knows better about medications.